# Parsing JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, each

I've got this JSON object:

```
({a1:-1,a2:null, messages:[{b1:message1, b2:message2, b3:message3, ... }]})
```

How do I loop through the messages pairs using jQuery's .each (without hardcoding the b1,b2,b3,message1,message2,message3).

Comment: Side note, that's invalid JSON.

Comment: It's also worth stating that there is no such thing as a "JSON object"!  JSON is by definition a string.  As soon as it ceases to be a string, it's just a JavaScript object!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `data` is your object, you can use `$.each` for this.

```
var messages = data.messages;
$.each(messages, function(i, msg){
   $.each(msg, function(key, message){
      console.log(key+': '+message);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading the [reference for `jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).  Here's an apt example from the reference:

```
$.each({ name: "John", lang: "JS" }, function(k, v) {
    alert( "Key: " + k + ", Value: " + v );
});
```

Comment: whoa you expect someone to read the documentation for something? seriously now, by nice. :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sometimes it just takes an example to make it click. I realize now that I needed a nested each. Very cool.